# How to set acceptable file types in a Django form's FileInput widget

Tags: javascript, python, html, validation, django-forms

Is there a way to set the accepted file types in a django `forms.FileInput()` widget? I want it to accept only .txt and .pdf.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput), contain nothing. If this is not at all possible, how can we add the validation at client side for a django form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating an input tag with "accept" attribute in Django form using FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537362/generating-an-input-tag-with-accept-attribute-in-django-form-using-filefield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ideally do this when cleaning your form data and return an error if its not the extension type you want.

But there is a django snippet that shows an example of how to do this using a custom form field:  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/977/