# Generating an input tag with "accept" attribute in Django form using FileField

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a form to upload and save videos from iOS Safari, which supports the "accept" attribute of the input tag, for example:

```
<input type=file accept="video/*">
```

lets you shoot and upload new video or select a video file on the device.

I've looked at the Django docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.FileField

but don't see where I can specify the "accept" attribute on input. Is this possible?  Can I create the input tag in the template and still use Django form processing to accept the file?

Answer (score 11):

Easy. In your model form, just make sure the `FileInput` widget gets created with the needed `accept` HTML attribute:

```
from django import forms

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'video_file': forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': '.mov,video/quicktime'}),
        }
```

Comment: Does this widget need to be specified alongside each field that uses it? If so, it'd be helpful to see an example.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Yes it does. Just add the fields to the `widgets` dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to do this, you can see some good answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648421/only-accept-a-certain-file-type-in-filefield)
Also, a personal suggestion (untested): after creating the form, set whatever attributes you want on it like this

```
    for f in form.fields:
        if isinstance(form.fields[f].widget, ClearableFileInput):
            form.fields[f].widget.attrs['accept'] = 'video/*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a simple step by including single line of code in you Form:

```
media = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'image/*,video/*'}))
```

which sets the accept attribute on input element on the front-end of django.
Note: this is also valid for forms.ImageField() also.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom widget that takes an `accept` param

```
class AcceptingFileField(FileInput):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, accept=['audio/*']):
        final_attrs = {}
        if accept:
            final_attrs = {'accept': ','.join(accept)}
        if attrs is not None:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)
        super(AcceptingFileField, self).__init__(attrs=final_attrs)
```

then you just go in your `ModelForm`

```
widgets = {
    'myvideoformfield': AcceptingFileField(accept=['video/*'])
}
```